# Unable to pass padded_batch tf.data.Dataset to tf.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` object as output from an input_fn used with a `tf.estimator`. Trivial example below:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

btr = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesRegressor(
    feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=(3,))]
    ,n_batches_per_layer=1
    ,model_dir=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'btr_classifier'))

def input_fn():

    # accommodate variable length inputs
    def generate_values():
            for i in range(50000):
                x_len = np.random.randint(1,4)
                x = np.random.rand(x_len, )
                y = np.sum(x)
                yield (x, y)

    # add a 'key' for feature_columns
    def to_dict(x, y):
        return {"x":x}, y

    # create a dataset from generator with padded_batch
    def make_dataset(batch_size=32):
        output_types  = ((tf.float32), tf.float32)
        padded_shapes = (([None]), []) 

        dataset = (tf.data.Dataset
                   .from_generator(generate_values, output_types=output_types)
                   .padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=padded_shapes)
                   .repeat()
                   .map(to_dict)
                  )
        return dataset

    def _input_fn():

        dataset = make_dataset()

        return dataset

    return _input_fn

btr.train(input_fn=input_fn())
```

This results in the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d7ca9ca451db> in <module>
     31     return _input_fn
     32 
---> 33 btr.train(input_fn=input_fn())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    365 
    366       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 367       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    368       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    369       return self

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1156       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1157     else:
-> 1158       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1159 
   1160   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1186       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1187       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1188           features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1189       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1190       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1144 
   1145     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1146     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1147     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1148 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\boosted_trees.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
   1932           config,
   1933           weight_column=weight_column,
-> 1934           train_in_memory=train_in_memory)
   1935 
   1936     super(BoostedTreesRegressor, self).__init__(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\boosted_trees.py in _bt_model_fn(features, labels, mode, head, feature_columns, tree_hparams, n_batches_per_layer, config, closed_form_grad_and_hess_fn, example_id_column_name, weight_column, train_in_memory, name)
   1075     else:
   1076       input_feature_list = _get_transformed_features(
-> 1077           features, sorted_feature_columns, bucket_boundaries_dict)
   1078       if example_id_column_name:
   1079         example_ids = features[example_id_column_name]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\boosted_trees.py in _get_transformed_features(features, sorted_feature_columns, bucket_boundaries_dict)
    102   return _get_transformed_features_and_merge_with_previously_transformed(
    103       features, sorted_feature_columns, sorted_feature_columns,
--> 104       bucket_boundaries_dict)
    105 
    106 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\boosted_trees.py in _get_transformed_features_and_merge_with_previously_transformed(features, sorted_feature_columns, all_sorted_columns, bucket_boundaries_dict, already_transformed_features)
    171                          'than 2, but column `{}` got: {}'.format(
    172                              source_name, column.shape))
--> 173       unstacked = array_ops.unstack(tensor, axis=1)
    174       if not bucket_boundaries_dict:
    175         result_features.extend(unstacked)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpuenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py in unstack(value, num, axis, name)
   1198       num = value_shape.dims[axis].value
   1199   if num is None:
-> 1200     raise ValueError("Cannot infer num from shape %s" % value_shape)
   1201   return gen_array_ops.unpack(value, num=num, axis=axis, name=name)
   1202 

ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, ?)
```

I was able to train a tf.keras model with a slightly modified version where there are no formats for the required `feature_columns` argument. Am I labeling by variant_dataset 'x' incorrectly? I am expecting this to simply pass to the estimator like any other dataset api. The piece I'm not very familiar with and attempting to become more familiar with is the use of `padded_batch` and if there are other considerations I may need to consider when using.